# Does traffic still go through Tor with this Exception Error in aria2c?

Tags: linux, information-leaks, proxy-leaks, ip-address-leak

On Ubuntu (running Tor) I set a system wide proxy from **Settings > Network > Network Proxy** as below:

```
Socket Host:    127.0.0.1    9050
```

Tried some apps like web browsers and they indicated a changed IP.

Then used [`aria2c`](http://aria2.sourceforge.net/) (similar to `wget`) within the terminal but got this warning, although the app continued downloading:

```
$ aria2c http://.../..linux.tgz
Caught Error while parsing environment variable 'all_proxy'
Exception: [AbstractOptionHandler.cc:69] errorCode=28 We encountered a problem while processing the option '--all-proxy'.
  -> [OptionHandlerImpl.cc:508] errorCode=1 unrecognized proxy format
```

I wonder If it used Tor for communication or just connected directly without Tor?
How could I check the IP of an app in the same situation (terminal app) while it reached a third-party site?

Answer (score 1):

You could capture the traffic with a tool like WireShark.
If it logs a direct connect to the used URL then the app is not using the Tor Socks Proxy.

torify is maybe also an alternative for you, it easily tunnels the network traffic through tor without having to configure the app you want to execute. A tutorial can be found [here](http://linuxaria.com/howto/how-to-anonymize-the-programs-from-your-terminal-with-torify)